# How does one refer to a changed name in German?

Tags: phrase-request

In America, there was a very famous investment writer named *Benjamin Graham*, who was Warren Buffett's teacher. But his birth name was actually *Benjamin Grossbaum*, a German name he changed during World War I.

What would be the term for the other name, *Benjamin Grossbaum*? Would it be "der ursprüngliche Name" (the original name)?

And how would one refer to the *new name*, Benjamin Graham?

Comment: When you want to mention the birth name right away with the current one, you use `geborene[r]`. *Benjamin Graham geb. Grossbaum war ein...* ([see here](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/geboren))

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would use:

> Geburtsname

for the original name as this is a legal term for a child's default surname (see [§ 1616 BGB](http://bundesrecht.juris.de/bgb/__1616.html)). "Ursprünglicher Name" is okay, too.

For a newly adopted name changed later, I propose:

> angenommener Name

(not sure whether translating this as "adopted name" is correct).

**EDIT:** AFAIK there's no fixed terminology for cases of name changing. Maybe this is due to the fact that changing its name in germany (and, i assume, in austria and switzerland) requires an administrative act. So, this isn't as easy as in [common law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_law) countries. See [Wikipedia on Namensrecht](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namensrecht) and [on Legal Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_name).